# Limit using l'Hopital's rule with logaritmus

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1+2\sin x)^\frac{1}{\tan x}$?

Computing $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\log(1+2\sin x)^\frac{1}{\tan x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}$

Here, where I can use l'Hopital's rule I get:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}=2$

But now my question is:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1+2\sin x)^\frac{1}{\tan x}$ = $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}=2$?

I don't think they are the same, but can I remove the log? Maybe it's easier than I think, but now I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+2\sin x)^{\tfrac{1}{\tan x}}=\exp\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}=e^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

The first equality you write is incorrect. You can evaluate
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}
$$
in order to compute the given limit, but they are *not* equal; if $l$ is the latter limit, then the one you're looking for is $e^l$.

Now, with l'Hôpital,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+2\sin x)}{\tan x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{2\cos x}{1+2\sin x}}{1+\tan^2x}=2
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(1+2\sin x)^{1/\tan x}=e^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative

$$\large (1+2 \sin x)^\frac{1}{\tan x}=\left[(1+2 \sin x)^{\frac1{2\sin x}}\right]^\frac{2\sin x}{\tan x} \to e^2$$